# What is a String Culture

Tags: c#, internationalization, culture

Just trying to understand that - I have never used it before.  How is a culture different to ToUpper() / ToLower()??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different cultures have different rules for converting between uppercase and lowercase characters.

They also have different rules for comparing and sorting strings, and for converting numbers and dates to strings.

Answer (score 11):

As SLaks says, different cultures handle casing differently.

A specific example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk2wykcz%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> In most Latin alphabets, the character
>   i (Unicode 0069) is the lowercase
>   version of the character I (Unicode
>   0049). However, the Turkish alphabet
>   has two versions of the character I:
>   one with a dot and one without a dot.
>   In Turkish, the character I (Unicode
>   0049) is considered the uppercase
>   version of a different character ı
>   (Unicode 0131).

Answer (score 1):

The Turkish I is the most common example of cultural differences in case mappings, but there are many others.

I recommend checking out the [Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/)'s information on this.

http://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html